# How to fill NaN values of a column using the mean of surrounding (top and bottom) values of that column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which has some NaN values. For example here is the df:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(100)
data = np.random.rand(10,3)
data[3,0] = np.NaN
data[6,0] = np.NaN

data[5,1] = np.NaN
data[7,1] = np.NaN

data[1,2] = np.NaN
data[8,2] = np.NaN
data[6,2] = np.NaN

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

here is the result of running the above code:

```
    0           1           2
0   0.543405    0.278369    0.424518
1   0.844776    0.004719    NaN
2   0.670749    0.825853    0.136707
3   NaN         0.891322    0.209202
4   0.185328    0.108377    0.219697
5   0.978624    NaN         0.171941
6   NaN         0.274074    NaN
7   0.940030    NaN         0.336112
8   0.175410    0.372832    NaN
9   0.252426    0.795663    0.015255
```

What I want is that the NaN values be filled with the mean of upper and lower values, just like below:

```
np.random.seed(100)
data = np.random.rand(10,3)
data[3,0] = (data[2,0] + data[4,0])/2
data[6,0] = (data[5,0] + data[7,0])/2

data[5,1] = (data[4,1] + data[6,1])/2
data[7,1] = (data[6,1] + data[8,1])/2

data[1,2] = (data[0,2] + data[2,2])/2
data[8,2] = (data[7,2] + data[9,2])/2
data[6,2] = (data[5,2] + data[7,2])/2
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

result of the code above is:

```
    0           1           2
0   0.543405    0.278369    0.424518
1   0.844776    0.004719    0.280612
2   0.670749    0.825853    0.136707
3   0.428039    0.891322    0.209202
4   0.185328    0.108377    0.219697
5   0.978624    0.191225    0.171941
6   0.959327    0.274074    0.254026
7   0.940030    0.323453    0.336112
8   0.175410    0.372832    0.175683
9   0.252426    0.795663    0.015255
```

How can I automatically do this in python?

Comment: Is possible use `df = df.interpolate()` ?

Comment: [Interpolate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) is the solution, as suggested above. There are also other interpolation methods available besides the mean, which is the default method used by the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [`DataFrame.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) should help here:

```
df1 = df.interpolate()
print (df1)
          0         1         2
0  0.543405  0.278369  0.424518
1  0.844776  0.004719  0.280612
2  0.670749  0.825853  0.136707
3  0.428039  0.891322  0.209202
4  0.185328  0.108377  0.219697
5  0.978624  0.191225  0.171941
6  0.959327  0.274074  0.254026
7  0.940030  0.323453  0.336112
8  0.175410  0.372832  0.175683
9  0.252426  0.795663  0.015255
```

If there are multiple consecutive `NaN`s `interpolate` it not replace by `mean`:

```
np.random.seed(100)
data = np.random.rand(10,3)
data[3,0] = np.NaN
data[6,0] = np.NaN

data[5,1] = np.NaN
data[7,1] = np.NaN

data[1,2] = np.NaN
data[2,2] = np.NaN
data[8,2] = np.NaN
data[6,2] = np.NaN

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
          0         1         2
0  0.543405  0.278369  0.424518
1  0.844776  0.004719       NaN
2  0.670749  0.825853       NaN
3       NaN  0.891322  0.209202
4  0.185328  0.108377  0.219697
5  0.978624       NaN  0.171941
6       NaN  0.274074       NaN
7  0.940030       NaN  0.336112
8  0.175410  0.372832       NaN
```

---

```
df1 = df.interpolate()
print (df1)
          0         1         2
0  0.543405  0.278369  0.424518
1  0.844776  0.004719  0.352746
2  0.670749  0.825853  0.280974
3  0.428039  0.891322  0.209202
4  0.185328  0.108377  0.219697
5  0.978624  0.191225  0.171941
6  0.959327  0.274074  0.254026
7  0.940030  0.323453  0.336112
8  0.175410  0.372832  0.175683
9  0.252426  0.795663  0.015255
```

Solution for mean:

```
df2 = df.ffill().add(df.bfill()).div(2)
print (df2)
          0         1         2
0  0.543405  0.278369  0.424518
1  0.844776  0.004719  0.316860
2  0.670749  0.825853  0.316860
3  0.428039  0.891322  0.209202
4  0.185328  0.108377  0.219697
5  0.978624  0.191225  0.171941
6  0.959327  0.274074  0.254026
7  0.940030  0.323453  0.336112
8  0.175410  0.372832  0.175683
9  0.252426  0.795663  0.015255
```

Comment: Thank you dear Jezrael. In your second solution, you are filling every missing value with mean of 2 upper and 2 lower values? Could you please elaborate further on the second solution?

Comment: @hyTuev - For column 2 are 2 consecutive NaN values, do you need replace them by `(0.424518 + 0.209202) / 2 = 0.31686000000000003` ?

Comment: @jezrael, for your last solution, if there are `NaN` values at the beginning or at the end of the dataframe, they will not change. So you have to add a `.ffill().bfill()` at the end of your solution, that is `df2 = df.ffill().add(df_tmp.bfill()).div(2).ffill().bfill()`.

Answer (score 3):

Using interpolate per your specifications (only one index row away):

```
df.interpolate(method='index', limit=1)
```

Or doing it directly using [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
fills = 0.5 * (df.fillna(method='ffill', limit=1) 
               + df.fillna(method='bfill', limit=1))
df.combine_first(fills)
```

Answer (score 0):

**More accurately using sklearn**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

mean_imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)

mean_imputer = mean_imputer.fit(df)

imputed_df = mean_imputer.transform(df.values)


imputed_df

   [0.54340494, 0.27836939, 0.42451759],
   [0.84477613, 0.00471886, 0.21620453],
   [0.67074908, 0.82585276, 0.13670659],
   [0.5738436 , 0.89132195, 0.20920212],
   [0.18532822, 0.10837689, 0.21969749],
   [0.97862378, 0.44390102, 0.17194101],
   [0.5738436 , 0.27407375, 0.21620453],
   [0.94002982, 0.44390102, 0.33611195],
   [0.17541045, 0.37283205, 0.21620453],
   [0.25242635, 0.79566251, 0.01525497]]
```

Comment: I think Imputer uses the mean of whole column and is not suitable for my question.